# Objective-C на Windows

Tags: windows, objective-c

Я хочу выучить Objective-C. Однако не готов платить бабло за девайсы Apple.
Подскажите IDE для Objective-C на Windows.
И если знаете, то напишите подробную инструкцию по установке плагина ObjectivEclipse для Eclipse. Не могу с этим разобраться.

Comment: Однако, увы, помимо самих ObjC и Swift ещё неплохо бы иметь аналогичные фреймворки в системе, или хотя бы родной системный апи для этих языков, без этого вроде нет особого смысла учить их вне контекста iдевайсов. Есть ещё такое: https://swiftforwindows.github.io (из библиотек пока что умеет только сишный stdlib и подобное и в unix-стиле + свой экспериментальный фреймворк wxSwift, думаю, что-то похожее на аналог foundation, иначе какой смысл).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неблагодарное это дело, сразу хочу сказать.  
Следующий план - это список тех действий, что я делал сам когда-то. Не говорю, что он единственно верный,  посмотрите, что написано в ссылках по теме.

1. Вам нужно поставить либо компилятор [Cygwin](http://sourceware.org/cygwin/), либо [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).
2. Загрузить и установить набор библиотек [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html)). Заметьте, что эти библиотеки *разительно* отличаются от используемых в родной (Mac OS X) среде, так как последние Apple постоянно изменяет и вносит новые и новые возможности. Поэтому никаких новомодных  фич (вроде замыканий) у вас в распоряжении не будет.
3. Сама компиляция будет похожа на что-то вроде

   gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o helloword helloword.m -L C:\GNUstep\System\Library\Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base

Ссылки по теме:  
 - [Installing and using GNUstep and Objective-C on Windows](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Windows)
 - [Compile Objective-C Programs Using gcc (пункт "3. To Compile Objective-C Programs on Windows")](http://blog.lyxite.com/2008/01/compile-objective-c-programs-using-gcc.html)
 - [How to Start Learning Objective C on Windows](http://www.ehow.com/how_5148893_start-learning-objectivec-windows.html)

---

> Я хочу выучить Objective-C однако не готов платить бабло за девайсы Apple

Так это, все равно, если собираетесь *серьезно* этим заниматься, то мак вам понадобится обязательно, а если несерьезно, то зачем вообще начинать?

**P.S.** у вас Intel процессор? Очень (очень-очень) рекомендую поставить Mac OS на виртуальную машину. Получите не только родной environment (с поддержкой всех новых возможностей языка), но и удобную IDE - Xcode.

Comment: На счет удобной IDE я бы поспорил.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, разрабатывать на виртуалке мог предложить только тот, кто этого не делал сам. Ибо это ад и боль. Если имеется интелловская инфроструктура, без особо уникальных железок, то вполне себе есть шанс после нескольких суток курения [клевера](http://konstantin.in/dc/aHR0cDovL2tvbnN0YW50aW4uaW4vdXBsb2Fkcy9rbGV2ZXIvS2xldmVyX3RzdmV0YV9raGFraV8zMjYyX2tvbnN0YW50aW4uaW4ucGRmLnppcA==) поиметь себе практически полноценный макинтош.

Что же касается «бабла» — вам в любом случае придется купить пару I-железок (ну, конечно, если вы не собрались писать под мак), а так же, каждый год оплачивать девелоперскую лицензию, чтобы иметь возможность что-либо своё на эти железки залить. Учиться, конечно же, можно и без этого.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент Microsoft реализует Objective-C окружение для разработки под Windows 10 (Совпадающее по API с iOS).
Вот ссылка ра репозиторий https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC .
Проект находится в стадии разработки, но "Hellow World" написать удастся.